# why does the c value gets repeated in the given code?

Tags: java

1.This is my code to convert binary to decimal but its not working.The c value gets repeated for some reasons.

```
/**
 * Created by Ranjan Yadav on 11.10.2016.
 */
public class BinaryToDecimal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner read = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
        int binary = read.nextInt();
        int total = 0;
        int n = 1;
        int c = 0;
        int number = 0;
        while (binary != 0) {
            c = binary % ((int) Math.pow(10, n));
            binary = binary / 10;
            number = c * (int)(Math.pow(2, (n - 1)));
            total += number;
            ++n;
        }
        System.out.printf("The decimal of the binary is %d", total);
    }
}
```

Comment: Say I input 1110111.  The first time, `1110111 % 10` is 1, and `binary` gets set to 111011.  The second time, what is `111011 % 100`?

Comment: Thanks The c should only be mopduled by 10 all th time.

Comment: Step through your code in your IDE debugger and examine the intermediate values at each step.  This should show you the problem quickly, and you will learn something.

Comment: I debugged it in intellij but i do not know how the debugger works

Comment: @RANJANYADAV You should really learn how to debug your code, your programming skills will go up 300% after that. Quick start: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

You were **increasing n by 1** and **dividing binary by 10 raised to n** at same time. Due to this, you were not able to fetch the unit's digit of binary number after 1st iteration. To solve this issue, you need to get binary modulo 10 (not 10 raised to n) in each iteration and also keep the statement of binary divided by 10.

I have simplified and also made some small changes to your code to increase readability. Here is the corrected main method :

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    java.util.Scanner read = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
    int binary = read.nextInt();
    int total = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int number = 0;
    while (binary != 0) {
        c = binary % 10;
        binary = binary / 10;
        number = c * (int)(Math.pow(2, n));
        total += number;
        ++n;
    }
    System.out.println("The decimal of the binary is " + total);
}
```

The code is working and producing desired results. Let me know in case you have any further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can just parse the integer with the `parseInt` method:

```
java.util.Scanner read = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
String binary = read.nextLine();
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(binary, 2); // 2 here means the string "binary" is in binary
```

If you're not allowed to use that, try this algorithm:

1. Create a variable `total` and make it 0.
2. Loop through the binary string with a for loop like this: `for (int i = 0 ; i < binaryString.length() ; i++)`
3. In each iteration, if the character is 1, add `Math.pow(2, binaryString.length() - 1 - i)`. Otherwise do nothing.